# Force delete locked table in a geodatabase using Arcpy

Tags: delete-file, arcpy

I need to update a feature inside a geodatabase on a daily basis via a scheduled python script using the arcpy library.
If the table/feature is being accessed or used by a user when the script is run, I am unable to delete it and recieve the error:
'Cannot get exclusive schema lock.  Either being edited or in use by another application.'

Many people access the features in this database and although in theory they should close down ArcPro at the end of the day, this is not guaranteed (people working late, or forget to close it).
I schedule the script to run at 2am when there is low probability of anyone using it.

Ideally I need a way for the script to just 'kick them out' regardless.

Question:
Is there a way to force delete files that are in use? Or does the operating system simply not allow this?

Tried:

```
arcpy.env = 'path\to\database.gdb'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.Delete_management('table_I_want_to_delete')
```

I was hoping that this would somehow force delete the file but did not.

- Tried simply asking people to remember to exit at the end of the day...but cannot guarantee that they will since there are many users.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can force delete a geodatabase that is locked (not good practice to do so). You should use [shutil.copytree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) and specify the ignore_errors attribute as True.

```
import shutil
database_path = r"C:\Users\user1\sample.gdb"
shutil.rmtree(directory, ignore_errors=True)
```

Keep in mind this is not really recommended practice and can cause some strange behavior for the clients that are causing the lock file. If possible, remove the process that is holding the database hostage before deleting.